# Rendering a link in classic ASP and then changing it with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I have a link that i am rendering on page load using an if statement in classic asp, something like the following:

```
// SQL stuff up here

<% if not rs.eof then %>
    <a href="#" class="link" data-mediatype="on" data-id="<%=somevar%>"><i class="fa-star"></i></a>
<% else %>
    <a href="#" class="link" data-mediatype="off" data-id="<%=somevar%>"><i class="fa-star-o"></i></a>
<% end if %>
```

I'm also using a jQuery click event to post some of the data to an ajax request, like so;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.link').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var mediatype = $(this).data('mediatype');
        var id = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/post/url/here.asp',
            data: { 'media_type': mediatype, 'id': id },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });

    });

});
```

If a record is found then the `data-mediatype="on"` and the `<i>` `class="fa-star"`, but if no record is found, then the `data-mediatype="off"` and the `<i>` `class="fa-star-o"`

Then when you click the link, it posts to the ajax.

On success of the ajax call, the page reloads using `location.reload()` and it works.

Ideally I would like to do this without a page reload. but im not sure how to go about it as the SQL needs to run to decide which link to show.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your asp page that accepts the ajax request should tell your frontend page whether it had accepted the insertion to sql or not, then you can use dom to manipulate which link to show

Comment: It does ... But at present, it just reloads using the location.reload()

Comment: When you post the ajax, is it meant to just toggle the current link to the other one?

Comment: It adds a record to the database, then on page load / reload the asp checks that record to see if it exists and renders the link appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to reload the whole page - just toggle the clicked link to be the other link (unless the click can change multiple links - it is unclear):

```js
$('.link').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        var $clicked = $(this),
            $icon = $clicked.children('i');

        var mediatype = $clicked.data('mediatype');
        var id = $clicked.data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/post/url/here.asp',
            data: { 'media_type': mediatype, 'id': id },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result) {
              if (mediaType == 'on') {                /* swap icon and mediaType */
                $clicked.data('mediatype', 'off');
                $icon.removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
              } else {
                $clicked.data('mediatype', 'on');
                $icon.removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
              }
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for posting that, im just adjusting it to my code at the moment, but just a quick question, where is $icon being initialized?